# Visual Basic Loop Through Array of Strings

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am trying to extract a sub string from a string using Visual Basic.

This is what I have tried:

```
Dim TestString = "Aberdeen, 1"
for i = 0 to TestString.length-1
debug.print(teststring(i))
next
```

What I would like to do is loop through the TestString so that it only extracts and prints the words "Aberdeen" WITHOUT the comma and the number 1.  So far, all the characters are getting added.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could `TestString` have other values? Should it simply stop when it finds a comma?

Comment: yes it needs to stop the loop at the comma and spit the word Aberdeen out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using VB.NET, you can create a LINQ statement which will take characters from the string until (but not including) it finds a comma:

```
Dim TestString = "Aberdeen, 1"
Dim toComma = TestString.TakeWhile(Function(c) c <> ","c)
For Each c In toComma
    Debug.WriteLine(c)
Next
```

If you know that there is a comma, it could be:

```
Dim toComma = TestString.Split({","c}, 2)(0)
```

Or:

```
Dim toComma = TestString.Substring(0, TestString.IndexOf(","c))
```

Comment: This is awesome.  Thank you very much.  I'm new to VB and have been trying to work this one out.  Thanks for your help.